# read tab-separated data into to R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following tab-separated data. I want to read it as a `tibble` or data.frame`. How do I read this type of data?

```
#
# Data-value qualification codes included in this output:
# 
# 
agency_cd   site_no datetime    3423_00060_00003    3423_00060_00003_cd
5s  15s 20d 14n 10s
USGS    07055875    2021-09-02  2.42    P
USGS    07055875    2021-09-03  2.19    P
USGS    07055875    2021-09-04  2.18    P
USGS    07055875    2021-09-05      
USGS    07055875    2021-09-06      
USGS    07055875    2021-09-07  5.50    P
#
# Data-value qualification codes included in this output:
# 
agency_cd   site_no datetime    3423_00060_00003    3423_00060_00003_cd
5s  15s 20d 14n 10s
USGS    07056000    2020-09-08  277 A
USGS    07056000    2020-09-09  231 A
```

Expected output:

```
   agency_cd site_no  datetime   `3557_00065_00003` `3557_00065_00003_cd`
   <chr>     <chr>    <date>                  <dbl> <chr>                
 1 USGS      07074850 1938-01-01               23.0 A                    
 2 USGS      07074850 1938-01-02               22.2 A
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output?  Does the `#` character also in the lines

Comment: How do you go from dates in `2020/21` to dates in `1938`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be better to read with `readLines` i.e. after reading the file with `readLines`, use `grep` to detect lines that are not having `#` or digits (`\\d+`) at the start (`^`) of the lines, then use `split` to split the lines into a `list`, based on the 'agency_id' substring, read with `read.table` while looping over the `list` with `map`, and do the conversion of `Date` column

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map_dfr(split(lines2, cumsum(grepl('agency_cd', lines2))), 
     ~ read.table(text = .x, header = TRUE, fill = TRUE, 
       check.names = FALSE)) %>% 
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(datetime = as.Date(datetime)) %>%
    as_tibble
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 5
  agency_cd site_no datetime   `3423_00060_00003` `3423_00060_00003_cd`
  <chr>       <int> <date>                  <dbl> <chr>                
1 USGS      7055875 2021-09-02               2.42 "P"                  
2 USGS      7055875 2021-09-03               2.19 "P"                  
3 USGS      7055875 2021-09-04               2.18 "P"                  
4 USGS      7055875 2021-09-05              NA    ""                   
5 USGS      7055875 2021-09-06              NA    ""                   
6 USGS      7055875 2021-09-07               5.5  "P"                  
7 USGS      7056000 2020-09-08             277    "A"                  
8 USGS      7056000 2020-09-09             231    "A"
```

#### data

```
lines <- readLines('file.txt')
# or directly read it
lines <- readLines(textConnection("#
# Data-value qualification codes included in this output:
# 
# 
agency_cd   site_no datetime    3423_00060_00003    3423_00060_00003_cd
5s  15s 20d 14n 10s
USGS    07055875    2021-09-02  2.42    P
USGS    07055875    2021-09-03  2.19    P
USGS    07055875    2021-09-04  2.18    P
USGS    07055875    2021-09-05      
USGS    07055875    2021-09-06      
USGS    07055875    2021-09-07  5.50    P
#
# Data-value qualification codes included in this output:
# 
agency_cd   site_no datetime    3423_00060_00003    3423_00060_00003_cd
5s  15s 20d 14n 10s
USGS    07056000    2020-09-08  277 A
USGS    07056000    2020-09-09  231 A"))


lines2 <- lines[!grepl("^(#|\\d+)", lines)]
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work. But, the code stoped when there are missing data like data in the updated question. How do I deal with this issue?

Comment: @hrkshr that needs only `fill = TRUE` (updated the post)

Answer (score 2):

If your file is named `test` then we could use `read.csv`, and then data wrangling with `dplyr` and for date `lubridate`:

```
read.csv("~/Data exploration/test", sep="") %>% 
    slice(-1) %>% 
    as_tibble() %>% 
    type.convert(as.is =TRUE) %>% 
    mutate(datetime = lubridate::ymd(datetime))
```

output:

```
  agency_cd site_no datetime   X3423_00060_00003 X3423_00060_00003_cd
  <chr>       <int> <date>                 <dbl> <chr>               
1 USGS      7055875 2021-09-02              2.42 P                   
2 USGS      7055875 2021-09-03              2.19 P                   
3 USGS      7055875 2021-09-04              2.18 P                   
4 USGS      7055875 2021-09-05              7.16 P                   
5 USGS      7055875 2021-09-06              9.28 P                   
6 USGS      7055875 2021-09-07              5.5  P
```

Answer (score 0):

The `read_table()` function from the readr package is built to work with whitespace separated data. Here's a very simple solution that stays completely within the tidyverse suite of packages:

```
require(tidyverse)
fpath <- "/Your/Filepath/Here"

df_in <- read_table(file = fpath,
                    col_types = "ccDdc",
                    skip = 4) %>%
  filter(!grepl("^(\\#|\\d+)", agency_cd),
         !agency_cd == "agency_cd")
```